# How to convert Optional<List<A>> to Optional<List<B>>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

Let's say I have a method:

```
B someMethod(A) {
    // ...
}
```

And I have an `Optional<List<A>>`, how can I convert it to `Optional<List<B>>`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) to change `Optional` of one thing to `Optional` of another:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

Optional<List<B>> optListB = optListA.map(
        listOfA -> listOfA.stream()
                .map(SomeClass::someMethod)
                .collect(toList())
);
```

(assuming `someMethod` is a static method of `SomeClass`)